# How do I restore wireless access and my wireless connections after using an ethernet cable?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, 64-bit, ethernet

Superuser doesn't explicitly list this problem, so I'm documenting it here. I have a standard Windows 7 x64 (Home Premium) Asus laptop and have been using **wireless** for years.

I then recently took it to work, and used an ethernet cable connection at my work place. When I returned home, I could not connect to wireless networks nor did any networks appear in my "Wireless Network Connection" list in my systray. My home network has never changed. But using an ethernet cable seemed to confuse Windows ability to distinguish between wired and wireless.

Despite my wireless adapter in "Network and Sharing center" stating wireless was working properly, no networks appear in the list, and I can only access internet by continuing to use an ethernet cable. How can I get my wireless access working again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research it seems that many users do have this problem through different scenarios, but all have a common event, using an ethernet cable during a period when their wireless was working perfectly, then losing their wireless functionality immediately after using an ethernet cable. (I am convinced this is a Windows bug.)

The solution I found that worked for me can be found [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/no-wireless-networks-showing-in-windows-7-64-bit/13f4d620-a744-4b1f-8821-7f7dd1cf8790).

Basically, you need to un-install the "Client For Microsoft Networks" driver for the relevant wireless network adapter to clean up the mess. (First make sure you're not using an ethernet for re-establishing wireless connection). I have re-posted the steps from the above link in case that link disappears:

1. Goto Network and Sharing Center
2. Goto "Change Adapter Settings"
   [image: Change Adapter Settings]
3. Right click "Wireless Network Connection". You should notice that it has a
   "Red X" with it indicating some problem. BTW Diagnosing it is
   generally useless.
4. Select "Properties"

   [image]
5. Uninstall "Client for Microsoft Networks" 
   [image]
6. Click OK, and restart your computer.
7. Repeat steps 1-4
8. This time however, select "Install" => "Client" => "Client for Microsoft Networks".

The connection should be re-established and the "Red X"
    for "Wireless Network Connections" in the list of connections (As
    you would have seen at the end of Step 2 above) should disappear, indicating the wireless connection is working again, (see below).

[image: Working Wireless Connections]

Pay attention to which network adapter you're modifying, Note there may be more than one wireless connection, for instance the "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport" is not relevant; You need to select the dedicated device,  (such as the Atheros wireless adapter in my case)

This solution restored my wireless access and my sanity. One way to avoid this problem in the first place is to "disable" the wifi connection first before switching to an ethernet cable. Hope it helps you...

Comment: Never had this issue in all my years as a windows user (w98), strange.

Comment: Yeah.. It was, I have never had this problem before either for years of windows use. But I think what ruined the configuration was that i was connecting via wireless at work, then swapping to ethernet a couple of times....